# RSA block by block encryption produces blank output for files larger than 1kb

Tags: java, file, encryption, cryptography, output

I'm not opening this thread for AES or other encryptions because this is what I'm going to use to encrypt the keys of AES and other encryptions. I've gathered several codes from StackOverflow and a few other sites and edited it to fit my program however while trying to do a block by block encryption using RSA problem is I can only encrypt small text files of size 1 kilobyte. Encryption and Decryption of text files are working fine. However, encrypting pictures and ANY files **larger** than 1 kilobyte will produce a **blank** encrypted file.

I would like to ask help if anyone can help me point out where the piece of code causes files greater than 1 kilobyte causes a blank output file/encrypted file. This piece of code works for AES but I'm not sure why it doesn't work on RSA encryption. The problem starts at `Encrypt_File` somewhere around the loop where it reads it.

Code:

```
public static final String ALGORITHM = "RSA";
private static final short KEY_LENGTH = 1024;
private static final short KEY_BYTES = 32;
private static final String CIPHER_EXTENSION = ".cgfile";

public void Encrypt_File(Path path_fileToEncrypt) {
    //get file name and the new file name
    String fileName = path_fileToEncrypt.getFileName().toString();
    String encryptedFileName = fileName+CIPHER_EXTENSION;
    String pathToEncryptedFile = path_fileToEncrypt.getParent()+File.separator+encryptedFileName;

    //attempt to open the public key
    try (ObjectInputStream publicKeyFile = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(PUBLIC_KEY_FILE))) {
        //load the key
        PublicKey publicKey = (PublicKey) publicKeyFile.readObject();

        // load file to encrypt and inputstream
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(path_fileToEncrypt.toString()));

        // init the cipher
        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);

        CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(pathToEncryptedFile),cipher);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[KEY_BYTES];
        int count;
        while((count = fileInputStream.read(buffer))>0){
            cos.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }

        //close
        fileInputStream.close();
        cos.close();
        //delete fileToEncrypt since we have the encrypted file now
        DeleteFile(new File(path_fileToEncrypt.toString()));
        System.out.println("Finished encrypting "+ fileName +" It's new file name is "+ encryptedFileName);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        CGcipher rsaencrypt = new CGcipher();
        Path pathTosecret = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "pic.png");
        // Encrypt the string using the public key
        rsaencrypt.Encrypt_File(pathTosecret);
        //rsaencrypt.Decrypt_File(pathTosecret);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: @LukePark Well, it would still protect for confidentiality. Integrity and *of course* authenticity would not be protected but that's not the case for AES/CBC either. It's both space and CPU-time inefficient of course and protection against timing attacks could be an issue. But top 5 worse things? Nah.

Comment: Note that the code formatting (identifier casing, not using space before/after operators) and especially the exception handling made me cringe a bit. You may want to look into that (did you know you can put multiple statements in the try-with-resources and that you can initialize the cipher before the try-with-resources? I would also separate the reading of the public key and use `getEncoded` and a key factory rather than object serialization.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I did use multiple try-with-resources but not in this section because I'm still trying to figure out what is causing the problem and yes the code looks awful. Regarding the space before/after operators, I will take note of that. Apparently, I'm used with C++ doing all the spaces. For the exception handling, I made it a simple catch block just so I know what's happening in this section of code although I know I could make it individual but for now I just want to make it work before I can make it look better. It's more of personal preference however I will again take note of that

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Just to clear out something. By separating the public key and `getEncoded` and key factory, do you mean by making a separate functions that handle them?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. If you store the key using `getEncoded()` it will be stored as a binary `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` structure which should be compatible with a lot of software (except Mickeysoft of course, leave it to them to use proprietary structures instead).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the algorithm RSA is internally expanded to mean `"RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding"` by the Sun provider. However, ECB mode is not actually used. It should have been named `"RSA/None/PKCS1Padding"`. So RSA cannot be used for larger data by `CipherOutputStream` as it doesn't implement any block cipher mode.

Unfortunately `CipherOutputStream` has the nasty habit of "eating" exceptions. This is why you get an empty string instead of a clear warning.

---

One of the problems with Java are checked exceptions. Although they certainly have their benefits, exceptional circumstances should not be part of a function definition. Checked exceptions are a well-meant but wrong method to produce reliable / error free code.

This is made perfectly clear by the `IOException` that may be thrown by streams. Not all streams do actually perform I/O so the exception is wrong. But because `IOException` is a **checked exception** it *must* be part of the `write` method definition. On the other hand, security exceptions have a **checked** base class called `GeneralSecurityException`. These exceptions *cannot* be thrown by a stream because they are not defined in the method definition.

---

Now there are ways around this, for instance creating an additional `secureWrite` method that does throw the exception. The usual `write` method could throw a new `RuntimeException` derived exception carrying the original `GeneralSecurityException`. These solutions seem to have escaped the designer of the cipher streams though; instead they opted remove the exceptions altogether or possibly throw an `IOException` where another exception is expected.

As a result the cipher streams should be used with extreme caution. Replacing them with a proprietary implementation seems best.

Comment: Thanks for the accept. Note that I also upvoted [Ebbe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44841479/589259) which perfectly explains why using RSA for bulk encryption is a bad idea. I suggest keeping to that advice - and upvoting the answer as well of course :)

Answer (score 5):

**RSA** is not ment for bulk encryption as it's quit slow compared to symmetric algorithms like **AES** (it's more than a factor of 1000 slower). The amount of data that can be encrypted with **RSA** in one block is dependent on the key size and any data that might be used by padding.

When you need the two keys of **RSA** and at the same time need to encrypt more than what can be in one **RSA** block, you would usually use [Hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem), where you encrypt the data part with a random symmetric key, and then encrypt the encryption key with **RSA**. This way you get the speed of the symmetric key, and the two keys of the **RSA**. But if you don't really need to have different keys for encryption and decryption then you properly should not use **RSA** at all.

As **RSA** is not ment for bulk encryption, the standard implementation's can't handle it when you try to encrypt more than what can be in one block - no logic is implemented for [chaining of encryption blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_.28CBC.29) with **RSA**. This would be handle for symmetric ciphers out of the box.